# "take off" is a noun phrase in "after take off"?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

[Boeing 737 MAX 8 in second crash in months](https://news.google.com/articles/CAIiENgQeCxRyAW_VTZHegyIHO8qGQgEKhAIACoHCAowocv1CjCSptoCMPrTpgU?hl=en-US&gl=US&ceid=US:en)

> Both were operated by well-known airlines with strong safety records
>   -- but the Lion Air flight went down 13 minutes after **take off**, while Sunday’s Ethiopian Airlines flight crashed just six minutes into its
>   journey.

I know "after doing something". So I guess "take off" here is a noun phrase.

Comment: No, it's not a noun phrase but a compound noun that should be hyphenated "take-off".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *the Lion Air flight went down 13 minutes after take-off.*

It's not a noun phrase but a compound noun consisting of the unsuffixed verb "take" + the preposition "off".

Note that it should be hyphenated as shown.

Other similar examples include "run-up", "take-away", "sit-in" and "hang-up".

Comment: But, there is the word "takeoff", without a hyphen. https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/takeoff

Comment: @Zhang MW are out of step. The Oxford and Cambridge dictionary hyphenate it. See here: [link](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/take-off) and here [link](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/take-off). It matters not; the important thing is that it is a compound noun, not a noun phrase.

Answer (score 0):

Use **after take off**:

> Both were operated by well-known airlines with strong safety records -- but the Lion Air flight went down 13 minutes after take off, while Sunday’s Ethiopian Airlines flight crashed just six minutes into its journey.

Since no one would know what you mean by **13 minutes take off**.

Comment: But why not after taking off?